# How does thin-blood alchemy interact with passive powers?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade-5e, thin-blood-alchemy

As I run Vampire the Masquerade v5 with some thin-blood players, a lot of question goes on the thin blood alchemy, even if I haven't the situation at my table yet.

One of them is how does thin-blood alchemy distilations methods work with passive powers. I explain myself:

Anathor Corporis read that you have the power until you swap with another one. So my ghess is that if you take a passive power, you have it until you swap it.

But what about Calcinatio and Fixatio. If you take a passive power (e.g. the emulation of almost any level one discipline powers), do you have it forever?

Second question, mostly for Anathor Corporis, but also if their is a permanency for Calcinatio and Fixatio:

Does the power evolve with as you upgrade Thin-blood Alchemy? Or does it stay at the level you made it, and you have to remake it to get the better version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does thin-blood alchemy distilations methods work with passive powers?

There is no defined duration for counterfeit powers that don't have a built-in duration, so it is at storyteller discretion.  You can have it last for however long seems important for the vampire such as a scene or a few rounds, depending on the circumstances.  Giving a vampire a counterfeit Resilience for the duration of a scene seems reasonable.  Letting them get it forever may be reasonable depending on your campaign.

The rule book states when the rules don't specify, its up to the storyteller.

> Does the power evolve with you as you upgrade Thin-blood Alchemy?

If you made a formula specifically to counterfeit a level 1 discipline, that's the only effect you get.  You'd have to make a different formula to counterfeit a level 2 discipline.

Comment: ok. The first part of the answer is good. But you didn't understood the second part of my question. What I asked for is, for exemple, what happend if my thin blood player take the "resilience" power (+X to your health tracker, where X is your level in fortitude/TBA)? Will it stay at +2 until the thin blood remake the formula, or will it become +3, +4, and then +5 when the thin-blood upgrade TBA?

Comment: The answer doesn't change.  The formula's potency is determined when it is made.  If you make a formula while at TBA level 2, then later get TBA 3, you have to recreate the formula to get a stronger bonus.